# password-protecting Access tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a Microsoft Access Database with an interface for usability ... But now, all users have access to the tables of the database directly. I want to deny this except for those who are authorized i.e.: Password Protect the access to the tables not the GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no "simple" solution for this.

1. Access has a security-mechanism built in. Note though, that this only works for the "old" `mdb` format, not for the new `accdb` format supported by Access 2007/2010. Thus, if you are going this way, you are using a deprecated technology which will might not be supported in future versions.

   That said, here is a tutorial found on the Internet. The process is a bit complex; it definitely exceeds the space of a StackOverflow answer:

   [The Microsoft Access Security Apparatus](http://www.grahamwideman.com/gw/tech/access/accesssec/index.htm)
2. If you need a more future-proof solution, I'm afraid your only choice it to move the back-end (= the tables) into another database system, such as SQL Server Express. There, you can restrict access to the tables and grant access to your application by using [Application Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190998.aspx).
3. If you only want to prevent your users from *accidentally* messing up your data, it might suffice to install only the [Access Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=10910) instead of the full product. Note, however, that this does not provide *security*, since a malicious user could simply install the full version of Access!

Comment: [The "Jet User-Level Security Mechanism" is deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb421308(v=office.12).aspx#OfficeAccess2007SecurityConsiderations_ConvertingDatabasesAccess2007), in the sense that it is not supported in the new `accdb` file format, which is the default format for new Access databases.

Answer (score 1):

It's advisable to assign permissions to groups, not to users, because each user inherits the permissions assigned to the group. [this might help you](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/permissions.html)